# Como enviar formulario desde una ventana modal, sin refrescar la pagina que lo llama

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

¿Alguien podría darme ejemplos?

Buscando encontre algunos ejemplos, entre esos la idea de poner el target de un formulario a un iframe que se encuentra oculto, no creo sea la mejor solucion, alguien me puede dar un ejemplo?

Leí que con ajax se puede hacer, pero no encuentro como, les agradeceria muchisimo, es para un proyecto que tengo que terminar

Comment: con ajax (javascript) básicamente lo que haces es interceptar el submit le decís que no haga la acción por default, envías los datos del formulario y dependiendo del resultado mostras error o seguís con la secuencia. en el caso de codeigniter no te olvides de enviar también el token CSRF que el open form agrega (sino el ajax falla), hay un buscador en la barra de navegación ponle "`ajax codeigniter`"  y seguro salen ejemplos, si se te complica pon el código al que llegaste y lo vemos

Comment: no conozco mucho de ajax, tendría que ponerme a estudiar, pero como interceptas el submit? no tendrías un ejemplo?

Comment: en javascript con jquery es tan simple como `$("form").submit(function(event) {  event.preventDefault(); // ... resto del código`, como te decía usando el buscador podes encontrar varios ejemplos de ajax y codeigniter o php https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=ajax+codeigniter